# vagrant is not read my homestead.yaml

Tags: macos, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I guess vagrant is not read my homestead.yaml file.

$ vagrant reload --provision

```
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/ugurgungezerler/web/Homestead
```

my Homestead.yaml file folders configuration is:

```
folders:
- map: /Users/ugurgungezerler/web/sites
  to: /home/vagrant/sites
```

i also tried vagrant destroy and up

OS = OSX El Capitan
Virtualbox 5.0.20

Comment: What is the error or message that you get?

Comment: i dont get any error message
i want to map folder: /Users/ugurgungezerler/web/sites

but vagrant does it /Users/ugurgungezerler/web/Homestead